# Filter by child class type

Tags: python, django, polymorphism, django-queryset

Lets say we have a class `Place` with a class `Restaurant` inheriting from it :

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I have a class `Tag` related to places :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tagged = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name="tags")
```

For a given tag, how do I get a queryset selecting all Restaurants that have this tag, but not other kind of places ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to doing this is calling `filter` from `Restaurant.objects` with something like :

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(tags=tag)
```

But if you want call `filter` from the `Place.objects`, you must use one of Django polymorphism apps such as [Django-Polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in your parent model because Django not supports models polymorphism by default.

**Note:** Read [This article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/human_computer_interface/object_oriented_programming.htm) about OOP Polymorphism & [This article](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/django-patterns-model-inheritance/) for some extra information about Django model inheritance.